# Simulate slow/bad DNS server

Tags: linux, dns

**Goal**: on a Linux machine (e.g Ubuntu) I want to create a DNS server that can replicate the following behaviors:

- slow DNS: respond to requests with a configurable delay
- bad DNS: responds to requestes with errors (e.g. send response without address) or invalid IP address  (e.g. wrong IPv4 address, IPv6 address for IPv4 query).

So far I've managed to use the slodns from github, but that fulfills only the first request. And using the bind9 for Ubuntu, I cannot simulate these kinds of errors.

Answer (score 0):

There is a timeout and attempts setting in DNS [resolution](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/resolv.conf.5.html). You can use that to your advantage and specify a non-existent 1st DNS server with whatever timeout you want.  It will hang on to the 1st entry for the specified time duration (and also attempt specified number of times) before moving to the next (working) DNS.